# How to locally debug a Queue triggered Azure Function wirtten in PowerShell with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, visual-studio-debugging, queuetrigger

I would like to have some information about how to do such a thing.

I've installed the **plugins** for Visual Studio Code, I've imported the **modules** at the beginning of my PowerShell script, I've fill the **requirements.psd1** with the appropriate module names.
Still, when I launch the command, nothing happen.

My goal is to create a team in Microsoft Teams using PowerShell.

I put a breakpoint and it is never reached.
What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878667/how-to-debug-azure-function-queuetrigger-locally)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The link you've provided actually helped me out. For the users that will come to this post in the future, you have to wait until the powershell terminal displays some relevent information. Otherwise that means it is importing/installing modules. I did not wait long enough to see the messages I was interested in. Now I have plenty of error messages. I can start to debug properly now.

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question then! :)

Comment: @ameliapond, you should add an answer about your issue to help other members handle similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize the comments above as below for other communities reference:

> Just wait for some minutes until the powershell terminal displays some relevent information. Otherwise that means  it is importing/installing modules. We can also refer to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878667/how-to-debug-azure-function-queuetrigger-locally) provided by Mathias in the comments.